# code showing prime number (c++) using recursive function and without using any loop

Tags: c++

Thats all in title.
In simple i had write this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;  
int main()  
{ 
    int a,i;  
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";  
    cin>>a;  
    for (i=2;i<=a/2;i++)  
    {  
        if (a%i==0)  
        {  
            cout<<"Its not Prime Number.";  
           system ("pause");  
            return 0;  
        }  
    }  
    cout<<"Its a Prime number.";  
    system ("pause");  
    }
```

The main thing is WITHOUT using loop and with recursive function.

Comment: What is your question?  You would like us to write the code for you?

Comment: You have no recursion, only looping. What is your question exactly? Do you want us to do your homework for you?

Comment: I think "without using loop and with recursive function" means that OP wants to solve this using recursion ***instead of*** looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursive primality test function:

```
int test_prime(unsigned n, unsigned d)
{
    if (n < 2) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (d == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if (n % d == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return test_prime(n, d - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
unsigned n;
std::cin >> n;
std::cout << (test_prime(n, n / 2) ? "prime" : "not prime") << "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You mainly want to look at making the body of your for loop into a function that takes "int i" as a parameter. Then you put a test for i<=a/2 at the beginning of the function and call "function(i + 1)" at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on recursion that can also perform the computation **at compile-time** if an  compile-time constant value is provided:

```
constexpr bool check_divisibility(int i, int j)
{
    return (j == 1) ? false : 
           ((i % j == 0) ? true : check_divisibility(i, j - 1));
}

constexpr bool is_prime(int i) { return !check_divisibility(i, i / 2); }
```

Here is how you could use it in your client code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_prime(11), "Error!"); // Computed at compile-time
    int x = 15;
    cout << is_prime(x); // Computed at run-time
}
```